# font-face disappear changing browser tabs

Tags: google-chrome, sass, font-face, compass-sass

On Chrome (v. 32.0.1700.107) OSX, changing tabs, sometimes happen that the browser doesn't show me properly the font face. It shows me the default one (Times New Roman).
If I go on rollover on those texts the font come back right.

is it a chrome bug?

I import the font face with sass and compass in this way:

```
+font-face("MavenPro200", font-files( "MavenPro/Light/mavenprolight-200-webfont.woff", "MavenPro/Light/mavenprolight-200-webfont.ttf", "MavenPro/Light/mavenprolight-200-webfont.svg", "MavenPro/Light/mavenprolight-200-webfont.eot"))

+font-face("MavenProMedium", font-files( "MavenPro/Medium/maven_pro_medium-webfont.woff", "MavenPro/Medium/maven_pro_medium-webfont.ttf", "MavenPro/Medium/maven_pro_medium-webfont.svg", "MavenPro/Medium/maven_pro_medium-webfont.eot"))
```

There is something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced this too, definitely a Chrome issue. It is a logged bug which is reportedly fixed in the beta version: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336170